# Is it possible to store session in local db (DBF file) in asp .net MVC?

Tags: sql, asp.net, session, localdb

Could you help me please? I would like to store session in a local database(dbf) file. 
I was searching on the internet, but I could not find anything, about how should this be done. You can use an sql server instance to store session with use of aspnet_regsql.exe, however I did not manage to use with a dbf file. Please help.

Comment: You need to implement `SessionStateStoreProviderBase`. I suggest googling for a more common 3rd party format for examples E.g. *asp.net mysql session store*

Comment: Please elaborate your question! It seems like storing session into local db doesn`t make any sense. Database at client end do you really think it`s a sane thing? 1. use cache 2. use cookies 3. create dynamic flat files/csv with proper encryption.

Comment: Thanks guys for the answers. I was curious if there is a built-in solution by Microsoft with a quick setup for local db files, like in the case of sql server. But it seams there is not.

Comment: Lostcoder, localdb would be the same as csv files, but without encryption. I was curious if there is a built-in way to use local db files, which would be very easy to setup, and it would preserve memory as well. I don't intend to put that in production.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, we don't normally use Local Db in Production. Instead, you want to consider using real SQL Server.

Second, you do not need to store Session State in database, unless you plan to host in Web Farm or Web Garden environment. *To improve the performance, you can store View State inside Session State which then stores in SQL Server, but I don't think it is your intention.*

If you plan to host in Web Farm or Web Garden environment, you might want to look at [StackExchange.Redis](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis) used in Stack Overflow and Azure.

Comment: Thank you, but I was curious if there is a built-in way to support that. I don't want to put that in production.